# best WSO2-ESB solution for banking application

Tags: security, architecture, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

we are a co-banking solutions company.
currently we are developing a solution and we hope to use WSO2-ESB in our solution to manage our services
this is the brief scenario of our project,....

we have a oracle application server that generate various services.there are two kind of services
1.services that can be access from outside users
2.services that can be access by inhouse users.
****also security is more concerned

my questions are,
1.how to use WSO2-ESB in this scenario..??
2.is it one ESB or two ESBs and how??
3.what is the structure you are proposing ???

Regards,
Akila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one ESB for both service types. you do all the integration / orchestration in the ESB and whatever service you need to expose to outside world you can do it via WSO2 API Manager. API Manager will apply token based (OAuth) security for the services you expose to outside.

That would be the most easiest way to do it. Having a two ESB pattern is also valid one of external and one for internal, but you have to apply security ur self in that case.

Most recommended pattern is the API facade pattern where you front the integration platform (ESB) from an API gateway and control whats exposed to outside and whats not.

Popular use-case on [service integration](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/04/wso2-service-integration-apis-application-platform-an-end-to-end-use-case/) and you can find a presentation i did on an [API ecosystem presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/nuwanbando/the-api-driven-echosystem).

Comment: thanks for the post. but have a little question again.
also we are use DMZ layer to to talk with out side.
is it worth to use api manager + esb architecture??
then which layer you propose to put api manager...??