# best wso2 solution to use api manager and esb with a DMZ

Tags: wso2, dmz, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

currently we are developing a solution with some parts of wso2 middleware stack like api manager and esb.
my problem is,,
in our solution we are maintain a DMZ layer.where you guys suppose to put api manager??is it ok if we put api manager in DMZ are or outside all layers including DMZ or a put it in inner layer.????

actually this question is realated to the [best-wso2-esb-solution-for-banking-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529661/best-wso2-esb-solution-for-banking-application) question i asked before.

Regards,
Akila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Manager has 4 components. The API Gateway, Key Manager, API Store and Publisher. Each of these components can be deployed in any part of the network. So to answer your question we can deploy the API Gateway component of the API manager in the DMZ and rest of the components along with any other WSO2 Products in the DMZ. The below link would provide you with a better understanding on the different deployment patterns available with the WSO2 API Manager.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/API+Manager+Clustering+Deployment+Patterns